# Why does the console.log output during instantiation of a Promise object, but does not output when a ".then()" is called on it?

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, async-await, promise

```js
const promise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  console.log("working 1.0")
  setTimeout(() => {
    console.log("working 2.0")
    resolve([90, 70, 55]);
  }, 7000);
});
console.log("Hi")
promise.then(values => {
  console.log(values[1]);
});
```

This is the output that I get:

```
working 1.0
Hi
working 2.0
70
```

But why isn't it:

```
working 1.0
Hi
working 1.0
working 2.0
70
```

My idea being, since we are finally doing `.then`, wouldn't the entire function that I initialized inside of `new Promise()` be called ?

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Why would you expect the Promise executor to be called _twice_? A `.then` call has absolutely nothing to do with the function you passed to the `Promise` constructor.

Comment: The callback to the promise constructor runs *synchronously* when you call it, so it prints the first message and queues a call to setTimeout. Then the control flow moves to the log of "hi". Then the `.then` fires. But unlike the callback to the Promise constructor, the callback to `.then` fires when the promise resolves. It's not clear what isn't clear about this to you.

Comment: Because `console.log("working 1.0")` is only executed once.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function you pass to `new Promise()` is called **immediately** and it is called **once**. `new Promise()` then returns a promise object.

The function you pass to `then` is called after the promise resolves. It is passed the resolved value of the promise.

Calling `then` doesn't affect the function previously passed to `new Promise()`.